# Can't load external url from specific domain

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm showing an iframe from external DDNS url and it was working good so far. Example:

[image]

So the URL provider has now a new custom domain and it's not working anymore.

[image]

I've added the custom domain to `allow-navigation` in config.xml this way:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*ddns.net/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.ddns.net/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*ddns.net:8080/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.ddns.net:8080/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*CustomDomain.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.CustomDomain.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*CustomDomain.com:8080/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*.CustomDomain.com:8080/*" />
```

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: is it possible that the new domain is being blocked by your companies firewall? Are you able to access the url directly via a web browser or curl?

Comment: it works from my browser and also on Ionic via browser